# Pairs in R - Re-order variables

Tags: r

I try to make a scatter-plot matrix with a dataframe(here it is http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/). However, the order of the variables is not the one that I wish and I would like to ignore the variable train.

Dataframe order:

```
lcavol, lweight, age, lbph, svi, lcp, gleason, pgg45, lpsa,train
```

The order I wish:

```
lpsa, lcavol, lweight, age, lbph, svi, lcp, gleason, pgg45
```

For the moment, here is my code:

`prostate1 <- read.table("C:/Users/.../Desktop/prostate.data")`
`prostate=as.data.frame.matrix(prostate1)` 
`pairs(prostate, col="purple")`

I tried to add the arguments horInd and verInd, but I get the following warnings:

> 1: horInd" is not a graphical parameter
>   2: verInd" is not a graphical parameter

If anyone could help me, it would really be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
prostate1 <- read.table("C:/Users/.../Desktop/prostate.data")
prostate = as.matrix(prostate1)
prostate.reordered = prostate[, c("lpsa", "lcavol", "lweight", "age", "lbph", "svi", "lcp", "gleason", "pgg45")]
pairs(prostate.reordered, col="purple")
```

The idea is to select the columns you want, in the order you want, using the column names for selection.

Of course, it would probably even more efficient not to convert everything from the data frame into a matrix, but only the required columns...

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what I want! :)